# how to get last 10 business days if

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create dataframe based on last 10 business days. Also it should check whether the day is public holiday or not.
I have a list of public holiday.

List of public holiday is:

| Holiday |
| --- |
| 2021-01-26 |
| 2021-03-11 |
| 2021-03-29 |
| 2021-04-02 |
| 2021-04-14 |
| 2021-04-21 |
| 2021-05-13 |
| 2021-07-21 |
| 2021-08-19 |
| 2021-09-10 |
| 2021-10-15 |
| 2021-11-04 |
| 2021-11-05 |
| 2021-11-19 |

weekends saturday and sunday.

so i run the code today, which is saturday 27th Feb 2021, than
output should be like this

| Business days |
| --- |
| 2021-02-15 |
| 2021-02-16 |
| 2021-02-17 |
| 2021-02-18 |
| 2021-02-19 |
| 2021-02-22 |
| 2021-02-23 |
| 2021-02-24 |
| 2021-02-25 |
| 2021-02-26 |

Comment: Is the list of holidays stored in the dataframe column? If so what's the dtype of the column?

Comment: its a datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative to @pi_pascal:

```
hols = ["2021-01-26", "2021-03-11", "2021-03-29", "2021-04-02",
        "2021-04-14", "2021-04-21", "2021-05-13", "2021-07-21",
        "2021-08-19", "2021-09-10", "2021-10-15", "2021-11-04",
        "2021-11-05", "2021-11-19"]
hols = pd.to_datetime(hols)

bdays = pd.bdate_range(end=pd.Timestamp.today(), periods=60, freq="1D", closed="left")
bdays = bdays[bdays.weekday < 5].difference(hols)[-10:]
```

```
>>> bdays
DatetimeIndex(['2021-02-15', '2021-02-16', '2021-02-17', '2021-02-18',
               '2021-02-19', '2021-02-22', '2021-02-23', '2021-02-24',
               '2021-02-25', '2021-02-26'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: thanks. the code gives error dti not defined. Can you help me with what is dti

Comment: A precision about `periods = 60`: 60 is an arbitrary number but this number must be enough to keep 10 days after remove weekends and holidays.

Answer (score 1):

I did not test this code but it should work

```
import datetime 
today = datetime.datetime.now()
business_days = []
#holidays = [ your list of holidays in here ] 

i = 0
while True:
    temp_date = today - datetime.timedelta(i)
    if temp_date.weekday() in (0,1,2,3,4) and temp_date not in holidays:
        if len(business_days)<10:
            business_days.append(temp_date) 
        else:
            break      
    i += 1
    
print(business days)
```

Note: You need to format the days if you need the date to be displayed in specific format

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas built-in function [date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html).

In your case, it will be

```py
import pandas as pd
today = '2021-02-27'
businessDays = pd.date_range(end='2021-02-27', periods=14, freq='D').to_series()
businessDays = businessDays[businessDays.dt.dayofweek < 5]
print(businessDays)
```

Output like this:

```
2021-02-15
2021-02-16 
2021-02-17 
2021-02-18
2021-02-19
2021-02-22
2021-02-23
2021-02-24
2021-02-25
2021-02-26
```